# Image is Not Posting On Twiitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

```
consumer_key=my_consumer_key
consumer_secret=my_consumer_secret
access_token=my_access_token
access_secret=my_access_secret

consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key,consumer_secret,{:site => "https://api.twitter.com",:scheme => :header,:authorize_path => '/oauth/authenticate'})
 token_hash = { :oauth_token =>access_token,:oauth_token_secret =>access_secret}

#access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(
 # consumer,
  #config['oauth_token'],
  #config['oauth_token_secret'])
 access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash)
img = open("https://s3.amazonaws.com/fbappshq-assets/datas/7828/thumb.png")
#image_path = File.expand_path('https://s3.amazonaws.com/fbappshq-assets/datas/7828/thumb.png', File.dirname(__FILE__))
boundary = 'cce6735153bf14e47e999e68bb183e70a1fa7fc89722fc1efdf03a917340'
request_body = ''
request_body.concat("--#{boundary}\r\n")
request_body.concat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status\";\r\n")
request_body.concat("\r\n")
request_body.concat("#{Time.now.to_s}\r\n")
request_body.concat("--#{boundary}\r\n")
#request_body.concat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media[]\"; filename=\"#{File.basename(image_path)}\"\r\n")
request_body.concat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media[]\"; filename=\"#{img}\"\r\n")
#request_body.concat("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n")
request_body.concat("Content-Type:multipart/form-data\r\n")
request_body.concat("Accept-Encoding:gzip\r\n")
request_body.concat("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n")
request_body.concat("\r\n")
image_path='https://s3.amazonaws.com/fbappshq-assets/datas/7828/thumb.png'
open(image_path, 'rb') do |f|
  request_body.concat(f.read)
end
request_body.concat("\r\n")
request_body.concat("--#{boundary}--\r\n")

#uri = URI.parse('https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json')
uri=URI.parse("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
https.start do |session|
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  request.set_content_type("multipart/form-data; boundary=#{boundary}")
   request.set_content_type("multipart/form-data")
  request.body = request_body
  request['Content-Length'] = request.body.bytesize
  a=access_token.sign!(request)
  b= session.request(request)
   puts "b---#{b.body}"
end
```

it gives us

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Internal error","code":131}]}
```

how can i solve this please help me.

Comment: use http://rubygems.org/gems/socialshare gem to easily update on twitter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with [socialshare](http://rubygems.org/gems/socialshare) gem you can share messages(text,pictures) on facebook,twitter,linkedin easily.. so for your requirements you can do it in this way to post image,

```
s = Socialshare::Tweeter.new(:consumer_key => TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, 
                    :consumer_secret => TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
                    :token => twitter_user_token, 
                    :secret => twitter_user_secret)

s.twitter_user.update_with_media("text", your_file_path)
```

so this will upload image to twitter, you can more info available on this gem [here](https://github.com/pandurang90/socialshare).

Comment: It Gives us Could not authenticate you error when i posted a image on twitter . It only works for simple text posting on twitter